# Excluding results from resultset

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have a query where I have a `NOT IN` or a `NOT EXISTS` it really doesn't matter both are possible

```
SELECT art.aid_artnr
FROM ART ,EAN13
WHERE ean13.AID_MAND(+) = ART.AId_Mand
AND ean13.AID_ARTNR(+) = ART.AId_ArtNr
AND ean13.AID_VAR(+) = ART.AId_Var
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM TEP
        WHERE ART.AId_Mand = TEP.MId_AId_Mand
        AND ART.AId_ArtNr = TEP.MId_AId_ArtNr
        AND ART.AId_Var = TEP.MId_AId_Var
        AND TEP.Mngs_Mng > 0 
        AND TEP.SobeKz = 0 
)
AND art.AID_ARTNR NOT IN (
        SELECT AID_ARTNR
        FROM KORT
)
AND ART.LogimatKz = 0 
AND ART.TeBoKz = 0 
AND ART.GardKz = 0 
AND ART.DivArt = 0 
AND ART.BeschaffArt = 0
```

my problem is, that in the table `KORT` it is possible to have 1 or 2 entries for each `art.AID_ARTNR` or no entry at all.

2 different types of entries are possible in `KORT`, `TYPE` A and `TYPE B`

if I have now a entry for `TYPE A` for the `art.AID_ARTNR`, the statement should not show the result, which is working.

now i somehow have to also exclude if `TYPE A` AND B are in the `KORT` table it also is not allowed to be shown, which also works because there is an entry for the `art.AID_ARTNR` in `KORT`

so far so good

BUT

the results have to show IF in the `KORT` there is a entry from `TYPE B` but not from `TYPE A`, I can't figure out how to do it properly maybe its stupidly easy and i am just thinking to complicated..

maybe someone can help me

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern OUTER JOIN syntax.

Comment: thats a statement from about 20 years... i just want to fix my problem.. the joins will be updated later on..

Comment: Please add an [MCVE] including some example data (i.e. DDL & DML statements) that demonstrates the problem and the expected output for that data.

Comment: Sample data please. Don't attempt to describe your data, just supply some. Then the expected result from that data. (& Do not use images of data.)

Comment: how should the sample data look like?

Comment: just small tables of text is fine, or, DDL and inserts , or, create a fiddle at https://sqlfiddle.com or https://rextester.com

Comment: @Bertl-TeamRasi Something like https://pastebin.com/kLJVcZTb for the sample data - just update the column names and values as appropriate and use `UNION ALL` to add more rows to a table. Edit that example as appropriate and then edit your question and post it in as code.

Comment: So your requirement is to check if there is not a type A row in the KORT table? If so, then adding a where clause of `where <condition that makes a row type A>` to the KORT subquery ought to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not clear to me why I can't just write a comment to the previous answer from Used_By_Already. Anyway, @Bertl - TeamRasi,  I think you already solved the problem yourself in your last comment:

```
select * from kort where kort.kompos_feldid IN (SELECT feldid FROM fes WHERE fes.LAGID IN (SELECT PRM3_VALUE FROM PARM WHERE parm.PRM3_ID = 'VerRaumLagId'))
```

just add an additional:

```
or kort.kompos_fieldid is null
```

should work, not? I think you should rephrase the problem or raise a new question as at least I am a bit confused on your question as in your question you did not mention about this "KOMPOS_FIELDID" column in KORT table, just in your last comment. To me it looks like the problem is to get the correct list of AID_ARNTR from KORT table, so maybe just rephrase the question to this specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

To show IF there is a entry from TYPE B but not from TYPE A I think you can something like the extra subquery seen below using the sum of case expressions within a having clause.

```
SELECT
    art.aid_artnr
FROM ART
LEFT JOIN EAN13 ON ean13.AID_MAND = ART.AId_Mand
    AND ean13.AID_ARTNR = ART.AId_ArtNr
    AND ean13.AID_VAR = ART.AId_Var
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM TEP
    WHERE ART.AId_Mand = TEP.MId_AId_Mand
    AND ART.AId_ArtNr = TEP.MId_AId_ArtNr
    AND ART.AId_Var = TEP.MId_AId_Var
    AND TEP.Mngs_Mng > 0
    AND TEP.SobeKz = 0
)
AND art.AID_ARTNR NOT IN (
    SELECT
        AID_ARTNR
    FROM KORT
)
AND art.AID_ARTNR IN (
    SELECT AID_ARTNR
    FROM KORT
    GROUP BY AID_ARTNR
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN 1 END) = 0
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN 1 END) > 0
)
AND ART.LogimatKz = 0
AND ART.TeBoKz = 0
AND ART.GardKz = 0
AND ART.DivArt = 0
AND ART.BeschaffArt = 0
```

**But I don't know how you can use BOTH those KORT subqueries** as they seem to conflict with each other.

---

Please learn more modern ways of defining outer joins, using `(+)` is not the way to go any longer.

Comment: ok so i think i didnt explain my problem correctly. i have the problem that i cant differentiate the results in the KORT table itself. in the kort i have the KOMPOS_FELDID which is my indicator of the type but the problem is that this are storage locations in a warehouse so they are not all the same. i just can filter the second type of entry in the KORT using something like this: select * from kort where kort.kompos_feldid IN (SELECT feldid FROM fes WHERE fes.LAGID IN (SELECT PRM3_VALUE FROM PARM WHERE parm.PRM3_ID = 'VerRaumLagId')) so the LAGID in the fes table is my indicator

Comment: so if there is a entry in the KORT for my art.AID_ARNTR, where the kort.KOMPOS_FELDID = a certain fes.LAGID then it should be shown but only if only this one entry exists. if there is another one it should be ignored. but the problem is that there are art.AID_ARTNR's which dont have this type of KOMPOS_:FELDID and those also have to be shown..

Comment: Please do *not* try to *describe* your data. Just supply some sample data, and the expected result; Do *not* use images of data! Copy/paste as text. To create fixed width text tables you can go here https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ Private data can be omitted or changed so it isn't private. You will get an answer 10x faster if you provide sample data